# PowerAutomate convert a mail to PDF or create a PDF in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

I try to convert a mail to a PDF in PowerAutomate and save it in SharePoint

I tried different options but the PDF does not open properly in SharePoint (see ErreurPDF screenshots)

The only solution i found was to use One drive to do the PDF conversion (see attachment)

But i would prefer not to use my One drive as it is private and my flow is shared with other users.

Do you have another idea how to convert a mail or at least to create a PDF from PowerAutomate in SharePoint ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging OneDrive is the main way, you could create a service account. Then create the flow and use the service account's OneDrive.

Comment: I would like another solution which is NOT using OneDrive please